# Issue with custom array-type in Typescript (Property 'flat' is missing)

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am in the process of building my own array-type in TypeScript 4.4.4. First I created a new class that extends 'Array'. After some research I learned this is not ideal, but it worked.

I tried to find some info on my problem but always end up in articles not exactly mirroring my situation and problem.

Now I am trying to create it using something like this:

```js
    export class DBModelCollection<T extends DBModel> implements Iterable<T> {
    
      private _items: Array<T>;
      constructor(arrayLength: number = 0) {
        this._items = new Array<T>(arrayLength);
      }

      [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T> {
       return this._items[Symbol.iterator]();
      }

      /* all member functions implemented except for 'flat' */
    }
```

so I am sure to get only my DBModel classes as items. This works great.

However, when using a construct like this things go wrong.

```js
  class User extends DBModel { }

  const somelist: Array<User>;
  const otherlist: DBModelCollection<User> = new DBModelCollection<User>();

  otherlist.push(new User());

  somelist = otherlist; /* this generates an error */

  somelist = otherlist.filter(x => x.name === 'martin'); /* this generates an error */
```

The error is:
TS2741: Property 'flat' is missing in type 'DBModelCollection' but required in type 'User[]'.

There's a lot of these assignments in my code.

What I have tried is this:

```js
  get flat():T[] {
    return this._items;
  }
```

Then the error changes:

```
TS2322: Type 'DBModelCollection<User>' is not assignable to type 'SecurityObjects[]'.The types of 'filter(...).flat' are incompatible between these types.

Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type '<A, D extends number = 1>;(this: A, depth?: D) => FlatArray<A, D>[]'.

Type 'SecurityObjects[]' provides no match for the signature '<A, D extends number = 1>;(this: A, depth?: D): FlatArray<A, D>[]'.
```

So that was too simple. Then used the IDE (jetbrains) to generate it for me based upon the original function `flat`:

```js
  flat<T, D = 1 >(depth?: D): FlatArray<T, number>[] {
    return this._items.flat(depth);
  }
```

And that generates a huge error:

```
TS2322: Type 'FlatArray<T, 0 | 1 | -1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20>[]' is not assignable to type '(T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? FlatArray<InnerArr, 0 | 1 | -1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20> : T)[]'.

Type 'FlatArray<T, 0 | 1 | -1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20>' is not assignable to type 'T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? FlatArray<InnerArr, 0 | 1 | -1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20> : T'.

Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? FlatArray<InnerArr, 0 | 1 | -1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20> : T'.

Type 'DBModel' is not assignable to type 'T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? FlatArray<InnerArr, 0 | 1 | -1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20> : T'.
```

So, next step at least compiles in the DBModelCollection class. Notice the return type is changed to `any`.

```js
  flat<T, D = 1 >(depth?: D): FlatArray<any, number>[] {
    return this._items;
  }
```

This yields the following error:(when using the `filter` method)

```
TS2322: Type 'DBModelCollection<User>' is not assignable to type 'User[]'.
The types returned by 'filter(...)[Symbol.iterator]()' are incompatible between these types.
Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'Iterator<User, any, undefined>' but required in type 'IterableIterator<any>'.
```

or simply:(when using plain assignments)

```
TS2322: Type 'DBModelCollection<User>' is not assignable to type 'User[]'.
```

So, back to the question:

1. How does TypeScript know that it should call 'flat' on my `DBModelCollection`-instance?
2. What should the flat-method look like?

Thank you very much for helping!

edit: I am aware that the question itself flies in the face of strong typing, but I started this project some years ago and am trying to upgrade my project without editing about 10.000 lines of code...

Comment: Why not `class DBModelCollection<T extends DBModel> extends Array<T>` ?

Comment: @Dimava because that is exactly how I started. Except for the generic <T> behind the Array. What is the difference? Main problem is that the old class is not extendable.

Comment: what do you mean not extendable ?

Comment: Please show an not-working example of what you are trying to achieve (eg an extra function of array or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Oke, so I experimented a lot. What I ended up with is a lot of code that overcomplicates. Especially making the []-indexing available led to very strange code.

```js
export class DBModelCollection<T extends DBModel> implements Iterable<T> {
  [index: number | symbol]: any | T;

  private indexpointer = 0;
  _items: Array<T>;

  private indexedHandler: ProxyHandler<DBModelCollection<T>> = {
    get(target, property) {
      if (typeof property === "symbol") {
        console.log(property); /* this is where all goes wrong */
      }
      if (target.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        return target[property]
      } else {
        return target._items[property];
      }
    },
    set(target, property, value): boolean {
      if (target.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        target[property] = value;
      } else {
        target._items[property] = value;
      }

      return true;
    }
  };

 
  constructor(arrayLength: number = 0) {
    this._items = new Array<T>(arrayLength);
    return new Proxy(this, this.indexedHandler);
  }
```

The problem I get is that this is a 'catch-all' proxy when accessing whatever property OR the iterator. All I want is to get the []-indexer to work on the array part....

Also the `[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T>`  seems to collide with all this.
So I quit trying to get this to work.